# ¿Cómo hacer trigger que actualice un valor en otra tabla?

Tags: sql, server, sql-server-2019

tengo las siguientes tablas

```
DComp 
  IdDComp, 
  IdProd, 
  CantComp, 

Stock 
  IdSt, 
  IdProdST, 
  CantExt
```

Necesito que cada vez que cargo un registro en DComp actualice el registro correspondiente en Stock agregando la nueva cantidad a la existente en stock.

He realizado varios intentos, en unos no hizo nada, en otros borraba todas las cantidades y en el mejor que me salió, me cargaba un el valor que correspondía, pero me eliminaba el resto. Además DComp puede tener varios productos repetidos ya que se carga cada vez que se realiza una compra nueva.

Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan prestar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sin ver tus intentos, solo podriamos suponer que es lo que necesitas...

Comment: Sugiero que [edit] tu pregunta y agregues el código de los triggers que mencionas que has intentado. De esa manera aumentan mucho tus probabilidades de obtener la ayuda que buscas. De otra manera, esto más que un pedido de ayuda entre colegas parece un pedido por que alguien haga tu tarea/trabajo y eso no suele ser bien visto por aquí.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.